# Передача \0 в аргументе командной строки программы

Tags: shell, параметры

Как передавать символы, не набираемые с клавиатуры, в качестве аргумента вызываемой программы для платформ Windows и Linux из командной строки?

Пример:

```
./programm 123 456 "какие-то-ненабираемые-символы: например \x1\x0\x3"
```

Пробовал экранировать по разному с помощью "", '', ``, но результата данные манипуляции не принесли. Использовал \0, но в программу вводился просто 0.

**Добавлено:**

Через Python удалось запустить с нужными параметрами, но выяснил для себя, что передавать нулевой символ нельзя, ругается. Но всё таки, как сделать через консоль?

Comment: А какой программе Вы передаете эти параметры? может она "не хочет их принимать"?

Comment: @KoVadim, `#include <iostream> 
int main(int argc, char **argv){
         for(int i=0; i<argc;++i) std::cout<<argv[i]<<"\n";
         return 0;}
`

Comment: нулевой символ напрямую передать будет очень сложно - дело в том, что нулевой символ используется как признак окончания строки. Поэтому, если Вашей программе нужно получать непечатные символы, делайте свой "протокол".

Comment: @KoVadim, Как раз и думал об этом, что нулевой символ передавать нельзя ибо набор указателей на char *. Мысль подтвердилась, но с консолью так и не разобрался.

Comment: Если очень сильно нужен нулевой символ - тогда передавайте его как '\0', а потом в коде делайте замену. Только помните, что нужно будет отдельно помнить длину буфера.

Comment: А что ожидается в програме с аргументом содержашим '\0'? Какова цель?

Comment: @0xdb задался вопросом как  передавать непечатаемые символы в программу именно с консоли, и как она себя поведет при передаче '\0'.

Comment: Может это?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104093/how-to-handle-non-printable-ascii-character-parameters

Comment: @0xdb, именно оно. Спасибо.

Comment: @borat_brata тогда не совсем понимаю с \0. Чем это поможет?  В argv[i] его видно не будет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Bash воспользуйтесь [Ansi-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) в форме `$'...'`.

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

Внутри одиночных кавычек все `\nn` (*escape sequences*)  будут заменены до передачи полной последовательности символов как аргумент.

```
$ echo $'aaa\x1\x2\x3'|xd
000000 61 61 61 01 02 03 0a                             >aaa....<
```

Пример в вопросе будет выглядеть так:

```
./programm 123 456 $'\x1\x0\x3'
```